# Frameset: how to start fullscreen mode/fullscreen not working?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, frameset

I have a page that is embedded in a frameset. I cannot/want not to influence the page that defines the frameset. From the inner-page (within the frame), I would like to start the full screen mode.

outer page (defining frameset)

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
   <frame src="index_frame.html" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
   <noframes>
      <body lang=en>Your browser does not support framesets.</body> 
   </noframes>
</frameset>
```

'index_frame.html' (inner page):

```
</html>
<style type="text/css">
   body {
      margin: 100px
   }
   .button {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      border: solid black;
      border-radius: 10%;
      background: lightblue;
   }
</style>
<script>
    var docElem             = document.documentElement,
        openFullscreen      = function() {
           if (docElem.requestFullscreen) {
              docElem.requestFullscreen();
           } else if (docElem.mozRequestFullScreen) {       /* Firefox */
              docElem.mozRequestFullScreen();
           } else if (docElem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {        /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
              docElem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
           } else if (docElem.msRequestFullscreen) {            /* IE/Edge */
              docElem.msRequestFullscreen();
           }
       };
</script>
<body>
   <a href="javascript:openFullscreen()" class="button">full screen</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Clicking on the button (try to enter full frame mode) leads to the following error):

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fullscreen error
     at openFullscreen (index_frame.html:21)
     at :1:1

What needs to be added to allow the inner page to be shown in the full frame mode? Any solution? Full screen mode works, if initiated from the main page (but this is not option for me)

Many thanks for any thoughts, solutions...

Comment: Seems the right for fullscreen is not granted to child frames. Our solution was to do it indirectly via a global JS function defined in the frameset page. But since that seems to be out of reach for you, I'd say it's impossible.

Comment: @Semmel could you provide more details on how to do it? In my case I have the option of using global functions.

Comment: @MMalke I would define a function in the frameset as such `function fs(el) { el.requestFullscreen(); }`. From the child frame: `parent.fs(element)`. Except that it does not work! To my surprise I always get a "fullscreen error" when trying to fullscreen any element contained in a child frame! Although the frameset has `document.fullscreenEnabled = true`, that seems not to work for child frame elements. My original answer was about popups opened from frameset: They inherit the fullscreen right - popups openend from child frames have `document.fullscreenEnabled = false`